# Was Manasa the daughter of Shiva or sage Kashyapa?

Tags: scripture, shiva, identification-request

I am little confused here, I thought [Manasa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manasa) was the daughter of Shiva but wiki says she was daughter of sage Kashayapa:

> The Puranas are the first scriptures to speak about her birth. They declare that sage Kashyapa is her father, not Shiva as described in the later Mangalkavyas.

What exactly do our scriptures tell us?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

She is a disciple of Shiva but not his daughter.

She is said to be the mind born daughter of Sage Kashyapa in [Devi Bhagavatam 9.47](https://www.astrojyoti.com/devibhagavatam54-2.htm):

> 38-58. Nârâyana said :-- O Nârada! Thus I narrated to you the stories
> of Sasthî and Mangala Chandîkâ, according to the Vedas. Now hear the
> story of Manasâ that I heard from the mouth of Dharama Deva.
> **Manasâ is the mind-born daughter of Maharsi Kas’yapa**; hence she is named Manasâ; or it may be She who plays with the mind is Manasâ. Or
> it may be She who meditates on God with her mind and gets rapture in
> Her meditation of God is named Manasâ. She finds pleasure in Her Own
> Self, the great devotee of Visnu, a Siddha Yoginî. For three Yugas She
> worshipped S’rî Krisna and then She became a Siddha Yoginî. S’rî
> Krisna, the Lord of the Gopîs, seeing the body of Manasâ lean and thin
> due to austerities, or seeing her worn out like the Muni Jarat Kâru
> called her by the name of Jarat Kâru. Hence Her name has come also to
> be Jarat Kâru. Krisna, the Ocean of Mercy, gave her out of kindness,
> Her desired boon; She worshipped Him and S’rî Krisna also worshipped
> Her. Devî Manasâ is known in the Heavens, in the abode of the Nâgas
> (serpents), in earth, in Brahmâloka, in all the worlds as of very fair
> colour, beautiful and charming. She is named Jagad Gaurî as she is of
> a very fair colour in the world. **Her other name is S’aivî and she is
> the disciple of S’iva**. She is named Vaisnavî as she is greatly devoted
> to Visnu. She saved the Nâgas in the Snake Sacrifice performed by
> Pariksit, she is named Nages’varî and Nâga Bhaginî and She is capable
> to destroy the effects of poison. She is called Visahari.

Comment: Just for clarification & knowledge sake, is there any other scripture where Mansa is stated to be mind-born daughter of Lord Shiva? I am asking coz the popular serial  devon ke dev mahadev also portrayed her as mind-born daughter of Shiva. not sure about their source of info.

Comment: u can try  [this](https://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/books/Essence%20of%20%20Bhaagya-Bhogya-Yogyata%20Lakshmi.pdf) @Just_do_it

Comment: is there any other scripture where Mansa is stated to be mind-born daughter of Lord Shiva? --- Might be there are such scriptures but I'm not aware of them. @Just_Do_It

Comment: @jasmine That book also says that Manasa is a mind-born daughter of Kashyap. See this "Another significant „Amsha‟ of
Prakriti Devi is Jaratkaaru or the mind-born daughter of Kasyapa Muni named Mansa Devi, who has the
privilege of being the disciple of Bhagavan Shankara and is a highly learnt „Vidushi‟of knowledge."